# How to fix "no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list" when using getline with an int

Tags: c++

Im currently working on an assignment and am trying to use try catch error handling for checking a user's input is a valid int.

I currently have this:

```cpp
int inputValidation() {
    int e = 0;
    std::string es;
    bool check = false;
    do {
        try {
            if (!getline(std::cin, e)) {
                throw stringInput;
            }
            else {
                check = true;
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& er) {
            std::cout << "Error! " << er.what() << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    } while (!check);
    return e;
}
```

my issue is with the `if ((getline(std::cin, e))){}` part. I've also tried using `std::cin.getline(e, 256)`

When calling the function I'm using this loop:

```cpp
do {
        std::cout << "Please select a month: ";
        selectedMonth = inputValidation();
    } while (selectedMonth < 1 || selectedMonth >(12 - actualMonth));
```

This simply makes sure they can only input a month from the current month until December.

I'm aware that I can use `es` instead of `e`, however that defeats the purpose of the error checking. My only idea coming off of this is to check on a conversion.

For whatever reason I seem to be getting the error "no instance of overloaded function "getline"" and am unsure of where I'm going wrong. If anyone could provide some insight I would be very grateful.

Comment: You fix it by using the right parameters, [getline *always* takes a string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), not an int.

Comment: What is wrong with `std::cin >> e;`?

Comment: @Borgleader Thank you :) Is there a way to use that input before the if statement and then checking on a conversion? Thanks again

Comment: @mch I was struggling to get the buffer to clear and found that the loop would never break, despite the input being valid :/

Comment: @mch I think this was a problem with my loop - my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Version**

I managed to fix this by changing it to:

```cpp
int inputValidation(std::string message) {
    int e = NULL;
    std::string es;
    bool check = false;
    do {
        try {
            std::cout << message;
            getline(std::cin, es);
            if (!atoi(es.c_str())) {
                throw stringInput;

            }
            else {
                e = atoi(es.c_str());
                check = true;
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& er) {
            std::cout << "Error! " << er.what() << std::endl;
        }
    } while (!check);
    return e;
}
//In another function -->
    do {
        selectedMonth = inputValidation("Please select a month: ");
    } while (selectedMonth < 1 || selectedMonth >(12 - actualMonth));
```

**Working Version**

As of the comments I changed this.

(The only difference is this version doesn't include an exception)

```cpp
bool checkInput(int &input, std::string message) {
    try {
        std::cin >> input;
        if (!std::cin.fail()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            throw(message);
        }
    }
    catch (std::string e) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        return false;
    }
}

//Elsewhere -->
std::cout << "Please input the lowest number you would like to check" << std::endl;
while (!checkInput(lowestNumber, "Please input the lowest number you would like to check"));
```

Comment: That won't work. atoi() returns the converted int, not a bool indicating success. It will indicate failure only if the parsed int is 0. Reading a non-parsable string results in undefined behaviour. Use istringstream or strtol.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: @JasperKent I see what you mean.. However for some reason it's working for me and the assignment is due tomorrow. I don't wanna change anything unless I know I'm ahead of time tbh. I'm not tryna sound like an a** here, just have time pressures. I'll defo give it a look once I've submitted because I'm trying to get better with C++. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: It may look like it's working, but trust me - it's not.

Comment: Okay, I'll change it to your version - thanks for the help :)

Comment: I just changed it and now the if statement runs every time, despite getting a valid input.

std::string asText;

   getline(std::cin, asText);

   std::istringstream iss(asText);

   if (!iss >> e) {
    throw stringInput;
    
   }

Comment: Try if (!(iss >> e))

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

if `std::cin >> e` is not appropriate, you could use `istringstream`:

```
std::string asText;

std::getline(cin,asText);

std::istringstream iss (asText);

if (iss >> e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the message Jasper! I literally just fixed this and then saw your reply :/